# how to do forcefully rotation in landscape on a button click when device in portrait in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios8

I have a MainView in my App which have One Button ,on clicked of button a another view controller is presented on main Window .

the second view which is presented have another a `UIView` which is act as top bar view in secondView controller and have @ more button in left  and right.

Now on click of one button in second view controller's top bar view i have to forcefully change the orientation in landscape.

Prior to iOS 8 it is working fine but in iOS 8 it looks like the image shown below.

[image]

Any one , Plz help Out;

here view start from after leave some blank space..

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Arun

Comment: stack overflow don't allow me to post image ...so  Sorry For that tag. I am explaining as simple ....when we rotate in landscape the some space is blank on left side near about 256 pixel from left n then app view start.

Comment: Just add a link to the image and someone will no doubt edit the post to include it.

Comment: put the image in sites like http://postimage.org and add the link to your question

Comment: @EWit:Hi Ewit actually image not post...if u want i will send u that on ur mail ...pls give me ur mail

Comment: hii.. everyOne this is the link http://s2.postimg.org/lok52ltqh/i_OS_Simulator_Screen_Shot_01_Oct_2014_9_27_14_am.png

Comment: @EWit: hii Sir i have now attached the image ....the black space is my problem

Comment: can you show your previous code that was working till iOS7 but isn't working now?

Comment: @hariszaman:yes i will post that here                            - (IBAction)mnextClick:(id)sender
{ UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplicationsharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
 if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:YES];
  [self.view setCenter:CGPointMake(394, 512)];
     [self.view setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)]; [self.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((- M_PI/2)) ];
            
    }
    [self shouldAutorotate];
}